Moderator Positions Open - Nominations Needed
We are looking to fill available moderator positions here on Chinese SE and are looking for interested users. The decision isn't final yet, but we are looking at appointing three new moderators to the site, so let the nominations fly.
Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing extra provisional Moderators to fill those roles.
We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
The Nomination Process:

Nominate a user by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
Self nominations are encouraged. This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
Tell us about the candidates. Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
Nominees! Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.


I accept/decline this nomination.
Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…


Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:
We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

Have been consistently active on the site
Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation


Nomination Template
To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

<a href="https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/UserID">
  <img src="https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/flair/UserID.png"></a>
  <a href="https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/UserID">
  <img src="https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/UserID.png"></a>
  ###Notes:
  This nominee would be a good choice because …



How many moderator positions are open? All of them or just the three that were chosen in 2012?

@ChristopheStrobbe We're looking at 2 or 3 right now. It kinda depends on the response we get here.





Notes:
Experienced member of the community, very active in Q&A and moderation (review queue, flagging, etc. (2 steward badges!)) - polite and courteous.   





Notes:
I'll go ahead an nominate myself. 

I've been consistently active for over three years on CN SE.


3 years, 9 months

according to CN SE

I have tried to be pro-active in meta's community-building activities, see meta question: 

Chinese Language: Getting out of Beta..? 
I also have:

7 Offered bounties for 1,000 reputation 


Although not perfect, I have endeavored to be patient and respectful to other users; especially in my votes cast:


3,221 votes cast


I'm big on moderation, see meta questions:

No Moderation Tools For Accounts? 
Migration: Only to Meta?
Currently on CN SE I have:

274 posts edited
252 helpful flags

On review queue I have 

753 reviews on Low Quality Posts
335 reviews on Close Votes
128 reviews on Suggested Edits
117 reviews on First Posts
41 reviews on Late Answers
12 reviews on Reopen Votes

Also: I'm UTC +8, so hopefully helpful for those around the other side of the world.





Notes:
I will volunteer for this. I like the community around Chinese SE and would like to contribute more.
I have been active on the site for around two years, more so lately after I acquired some editing privileges.
I frequently review queues and cast votes, trying to edit or comment whenever possible.   
I also participated in the meta:
Recommend deletion for low quality posts
I'm located in UTC+1.
